# Python using hvac client to get authentication token from Kubernetes to login gives Call to deprecated function 'auth_kubernetes'

Tags: python

I am setting up a client that communicates with Vault from my Python code running i Kubernetes.

The code below sets up the connection, and it works:

```
client = hvac.Client(url="https://vault.xxx.yyy.zzz.com/")
f = open('/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token')
jwt = f.read()

client.auth_kubernetes("my-app", jwt)
```

However I get the following warning:

> DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function 'auth_kubernetes'.
> This method will be removed in version '1.0.0' Please use the 'login'
> method on the 'hvac.api.auth_methods.kubernetes' class moving forward.

Can anyone help me rewrite the authentication using the new login method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from hvac import Client
from hvac.api.auth_methods import Kubernetes

client = Client(
    url="https://vault.xxx.yyy.zzz.com/"
)

f = open('/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token')

jwt = f.read()

Kubernetes(client.adapter).login(
    role="my-app",
    jwt=jwt
)
```

I agree, docs aren't clear. This should work and get rid of the deprecation warning.